# Select the next DOM element after the current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show a div after a click event.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="more-items-link">more items</a><div class="more-items"></div>
<a href="#" class="more-items-link">more items</a><div class="more-items"></div>
etc.
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.more-items').hide();

$('.more-items-link').click(function()
{
    var currentDiv = $(this).parent().next();
    currentDiv.show();
});
```

How can I show the div of the current link where there is the click event? I tried many things and it still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to move back up to the parent in this instance, you just need the next sibling so you can call `.next()` on the link itself:

```
$('.more-items-link').click(function()
{
    var currentDiv = $(this).next(".more-items");
    currentDiv.show();
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UErUp/) for the above code

Comment: Strangely, I tried this in first, and it didn't work. Now it works! Thanks. ;)

Comment: I think it didn't work cause I had a <br /> tag after the link.

Comment: @gaetanm That would cause it to break in this instance if you are only using `next()` without any parameters. Adding the CSS selector to it ensures you are only picking the next element which matches your criteria :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.more-items-link').click(function()
{
    var currentDiv = $(this).next();
    currentDiv.show();
});
```

There's no need to use the `.parent()` method here, since the div is just next to the anchor.